# Groth'16 trapdoor for simulator

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In the zero knowledge definition of the Groth16 scheme (https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf) [Section 2.2], why would the simulator be allowed a **trap-door** in set up? The trap-door information contains the toxic waste that should be destroyed by the set up. In another word, if the simulator (a.k.a modeling a passive attacker) learns the toxic waste, would it hurt the security of the protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trapdoor is fundamental for arguing zero-knowledge. You can think of it this way: with the trapdoor, the prover could provide a valid proof *without knowing the witness*, and the proof would be *indistinguishable from a real proof*. This guarantees that nothing is leaked about the witness by a valid proof, since a similar-looking proof could have been generated without it.

Of course, the trapdoor should not be known by the prover in the real world - that would allow them to cheat.

In traditional NIZK systems such as Groth-Sahai, the trick is that the system parameters can be generated in one of two indistinguishable modes - one with the trapdoor, and one without. In the real-world, we use a setup that guarantees that the parameters are generated in the trapdoor-less mode (actually, we can also use a setup that generates parameters with a trapdoor, but in a way that guarantees that no one knows the trapdoor).

[EDIT - fixing an incorrect answer where I was confusing Groth16 and GrothSahai08, thanks to Wilson for pointing it out]

For Groth-Sahai the trapdoor-less mode is a uniformly random string. An easy way to generate the trapdoor-less parameters is to use a "nothing up my sleeve" method, *i.e.* a process that ensures that the outcome was not controlled by anyone - e.g. take the result of the last lottery, append a bunch of decimals of $\pi$, and hash the result with SHA2. Anything like that should work.

For SNARKs, however, and in particular for Groth16, things are fundamentally different: we do usually not have any way to make the construction work using a uniform random string*. We still need this trapdoor inside the string for the simulation (when we prove zero-knowledge), but now for soundness, we really have to make sure the prover does not know the trapdoor (and rely on a knowledge-of-exponent assumption to show that if they cheat without knowing the trapdoor, they must know the witness). In this case, the best solution is usually to generate this SRS using a secure distributed protocol with many parties, to "dilute" the trust. This can be costly and is not entirely satisfying, but it's a one time cost, and it is the best we can do (beyond just trusting whoever generated the SRS).

(*) We can do that for some proof systems which have succinct proofs, but non-succinct verifier runtime, such as [Bulletproof](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf). Achieving an efficient SNARK that only relies on a random string and has succinct verification is, as far as I know, an open problem.

Comment: I'm confused about your last paragraph. Isn't the SRS for Groth16 very structured? For example, it contains consecutive powers in the exponent similar to KZG's SRS. How would this be a uniform random string? Unless, Groth16 has a "mode" where it operates solely on a CRS. If so, would you have a reference for this?

Comment: You are perfectly right: I mis-parsed Groth16 as GrothSahai08. I should update my answer: what I said does not hold for Groth16.